# Getting errors after attempting to update log4j and remove display tag

Tags: maven, struts2, log4j, maven-dependency

I've recently had to update my log4j dependency as the old one was being pulled in by displaytag. I've converted all of the necessary tables, and things seem to be running fine on the front end, but I'm receiving the following error in the log:

```
Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class of size 703 
Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class of size 7373
Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class of size 778
Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/Base64Util.class of size 862
Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator$FqcnCallerLocator.class of size 1894
Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/internal/DefaultObjectInputFilter.class of size 2913




[2022-02-24T11:06:07.096-0600] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1645722367096] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/module-info.class of size 703
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:359)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:345)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:68)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:304)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2022-02-24T11:06:07.098-0600] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1645722367098] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class of size 7373
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:359)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:345)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:68)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:304)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2022-02-24T11:06:07.106-0600] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1645722367106] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class of size 778
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:359)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:345)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:68)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:304)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2022-02-24T11:06:07.113-0600] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1645722367113] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/Base64Util.class of size 862
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:359)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:345)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:68)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:304)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2022-02-24T11:06:07.115-0600] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1645722367115] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator$FqcnCallerLocator.class of size 1894
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:359)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:345)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:68)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:304)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2022-02-24T11:06:07.118-0600] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=deployment-jar-scanner] [timeMillis: 1645722367118] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while visiting META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/internal/DefaultObjectInputFilter.class of size 2913
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.external.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:424)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:359)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:127)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:345)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:68)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:304)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Below is my pom.xml:

```xml
<name>username-service</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dakuupa</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-crud-framework</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- above 2 dependencies are for log4j JDK 7 -->   

    
        <!-- below 2 dependencies for removing server warnings in glassfish about slfj4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

And my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <jsp-config>
    </jsp-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>SecurityConstraintLoginRequired</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>AllWebResources</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/personsearch/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/JsonSearch</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>AuthenticationConstraint</description>
            <role-name>userRole</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>ldap</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>userRole</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

I'm not used to posting on here, so please let me know if any more information is needed to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dependency conflicts then there's an option to exclude unused dependencies from the tree.

You need to have the correct version of [ASM](https://asm.ow2.org/) libraries on your classpath. This libraries are transitive from the `struts2-core` artifact.